# Openlayers2 and Google Maps Api aren't working on Android Platform

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, google-maps, android, phonegap

I have application that uses OpenLayers, Google Maps API and GeoServer
My application is running at Web browser and when I try to run at Android tablet (using Phonegap), It runs but OpenLayers components is staying behind the google maps.

How can I solve this problem ?

PS : When running at android, plus-minus button, red marker and layer switcher are staying behind the google maps.

[My Browser Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcO0L.jpg)

Comment: What happens when you use this sample: http://www.openlayers.org/dev/examples/osm-google.html? this sample works without issues on my Android phone.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe your linked example works but my application isn't working. anything missing :S

Comment: So now we have narrowed down the problem to your application. You'll have to check your code and see what causes the problem. Without looking at the code, it won't be possible for us to point out the problem.

Comment: I think openlayers with google maps v2 (javascript) is broken. Check out the example http://www.openlayers.org/dev/examples/google.html